# How to do multiple plot on the rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Data set

```
Product,Buy,Sold,Profit
Books,1111,2222,1111
Pens,2222,4444,2222
```

How to plot graph each rows. Here need to generate 3 graphs

First graph

- X axis is Books and Y axis having 3 bars (Buy,Sold,Profit)

Second graph

- X axis is Pens and Y axis having 3 bars (Buy,Sold,Profit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `plot.bar()`:

```
df.plot.bar(x='Product')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As requested need separate graph

Comment: Please do a little research if you want to make books and pens as two separate graphs. Good place to look is https://seaborn.pydata.org/. @QuangHoang has given you a great start. Can you tweak his code?